# How to extract only data from columns of excel file into Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, smtp

Inputting a hardcoded excel file that consists of working hours over a month, I'm supposed to check which employee has less than 40 hours per week and extract their employee id and name and send a mail every monday regarding their details. How can we extract only 5days of working days and calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

Html file for uploading the form is

```
<form th:action="@{/import}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" th:name="file" />
    <input th:type="submit" value="Import" />
</form>
```

Controller class is

```
@PostMapping("/import")
public void mapReapExcelDatatoDB(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile reapExcelDataFile) throws IOException {
    
    List<Test> tempStudentList = new ArrayList<Test>();
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(reapExcelDataFile.getInputStream());
    XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    
    for(int i=1;i<worksheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows() ;i++) {
        Test tempStudent = new Test();
            
        XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i);
            
        tempStudent.setId((int) row.getCell(0).getNumericCellValue());
        tempStudent.setContent(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
        tempStudentList.add(tempStudent);   
    }
}
```

Make sure to add the dependecy

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
<!-- excel 2007 over-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.12</version>
</dependency>
```

And make sure to connect spring with postgres using drivers

```
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxxxx
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxx
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

And also add model class for the column of table according to the columns in excel sheet after that you can easily access any column of your excel sheet via database in your code anywhere.